# How to monitor a folder in a pst to run code when items are added?

Tags: vba, outlook

I created a pst file called All Inbox and have rules to move all email from all other accounts into its Inbox.

I have a macro that runs all those rules at once (RunRules) to process messages (move, print, file, etc.) from the All Inbox/Inbox folder, but I have to run it manually.

I want to monitor the All Inbox/Inbox folder and fire my RunRules macro.

The code I've seen monitors the default folder. How do I specify the All Inbox/Inbox folder?

Where do I put the options, subs, etc? All in a new module?

```vb
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents objItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objWatchFolder As Outlook.Folder

    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objWatchFolder = objNS.Folder("All Inbox").Folders("Inbox")

    Set objItems = objWatchFolder.Items
End Sub

Private Sub olkFolder_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim xitem As Outlook.MailItem
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        RunRules
    End If
End Sub
```

Do I specify All Inbox as a store?

Comment: I am confused and do not understand the problem.  It is clear what All Inbox is, but what is the default folder if it isn't the Inbox?  Why won't NewMailEx work? Rules can be trigger macros, why won't a rule work?

Answer (score 0):

Your missing **`S`** on `objNS.Folder` Should be `objNS.Folders("All Inbox").Folders("Inbox")`

`Application_Startup` event Should be under **`ThisOutlookSession`** class module and you could also have your `RunRules` sub in the same madule.